# Is there a method to switch strings around '=' in eclipse source file

Tags: eclipse

I like to use dictionaries for function inputs and output. Here is example Python code:

```
def fun(d):
    a = d['a']
    result = 2*a
    r['result'] = result

a = 1
d['a'] = a
r = fun(d)
result = r['result']
```

Does Eclipse help somehow to generate: `result = r['result']` from the copied line: `r['result'] = result` ? Now I need to select first *result*, copy, select point in the beginning of code text, paste, select *r['result']*, copy, select end of line and paste. And same for all other parameters...

This "extra" manual work has annoyed me several years...

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Eclipse at hand at the moment to try it, but you should be able to do it with [Practically Macro](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro).

Record something like

> Paste, search '=' backwards, shift-end, cut to clipboard, home, paste, type '=', end, backspace (delete last char =)

You will need to test it regarding off-by-one errors (maybe '=' will be copied to clipboard and first rather than last character would need to be deleted), but it should work.

Comment: Next question, how can I install that to my Eclipse, Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)?